# Event listeners in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, events, asynchronous, coffeescript

I'm having hard time with this excerpt of my code.

```
_.forEach peerIds, (peerId) =>

    console.log "connecting to peerId: #{ peerId }"

    connection = peer.connect peerId

    connection.on "error", (error) =>
        alert error.type

    connection.on "open", =>

        console.log "connection to peerId #{ connection.peer } is open: #{ connection.open }"

        @connections.push connection

        @listenForMessage connection
```

It's a part of p2p chat I'm working on. Basically it goes through list of peer IDs, creates a connection for each and puts an event listener on each connection it has created.

Variable `_` you see is [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/docs). Variable `peer` is [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/docs/#api).

If we assume that `peerIds` is set to `["y", "z"]`, here's the rather interesting console output:

> peerIds: y,z
>
> connecting to peerId: y
>
> connecting to peerId: z
>
> connection to peerId z is open: false
>
> connection to peerId z is open: true

Why event `open` is called twice with connection that belongs to peer `z`? There is no way I could have changed `peerIds` from the loop inside, right?

I somehow need to make this run synchronous (without a) or simply correct while being asynchronous.

Expected output:

> peerIds: y,z
>
> connecting to peerId: y
>
> connecting to peerId: z
>
> connection to peerId y is open: true
>
> connection to peerId z is open: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure! Also, CoffeeScript provides a keyword `do` for it.

```
_.forEach peerIds, (peerId) =>

    connection = peer.connect peerId

    do (connection) =>

        connection.on "error", (error) ->
            alert error.type

        connection.on "open", =>

            @connections.push connection

            @listenForMessage connection
```